# Is there any difference in bash between using `eval $cmd` and just `$cmd`?

Tags: bash, eval

In bash, you can treat a string as command (and run it) in two different ways:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="echo -n sometext"
eval $cmd    # Not sure if quotes make a difference here
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="echo -n sometext"
$cmd    # Not sure if quotes make a difference here either
```

Is there any difference between the two? Is there a situation where quotes around `cmd` make a difference? What about performance?

Comment: Neither one is recommended. Use a function, not a variable, to store code to be executed.

Comment: `cmd () { echo -n sometext; }`

Comment: Yeah I know, code-injection and stuff. It has it's place sometimes, though. Also not that much of a problem with shell scripts vs. web applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference :)
You need to first understand how `eval` works. Basically, `eval` is a shell builtin command. Whatever argument passed to `eval` is first treated as a string. 
Let's take below example:

```
 cmd="echo -n sometext"
 eval $cmd
```

The complete run process of this command is as follows:

```
 eval $cmd
 + eval echo -n sometext
 ++ echo -n sometext
 sometext
```

Here, first $cmd first got evaluated and then the whole string was passed to eval command as argument. Then eval evaluates the command considering the first argument as a "command or an executable file" and then run as a normal command. So, here there is 2 rounds of evaluation getting performed for the execution of the complete command. 
(NOTE: The `+` symbol above shows the step wise execution when used in `bash -x` mode)

The main consequence lies in variable expansion. With `eval` we have two rounds of expansion. One of course, when `cmd` is defined, and one when `eval` is executed.

```
var="inital"
cmd="echo -n $var \$var"
var="chanded in the mean time"
eval $cmd
inital chanded in the mean time
```

However, when you use `$cmd` only without eval, bash takes care of everything from variable expansion to the final execution. Just see the debugging window details while running only `$cmd`

```
$cmd
+ echo -n sometext
sometext
```

Performance wise, direct use of `$cmd` is good enough. However, when you are trying to use some external command or a script which requires environment changes, you can use `eval`

In `cmd="echo -n sometext"`, quotes are necessary, otherwise after "echo", bash will raise an error like below:

```
cmd=echo -n sometext
-n: command not found
```

I hope the explanation will be helpful.

Comment: I get it, thanks. If you don't mind, I'll edit your answer with a few points. The quote thing was asking whether `eval "$cmd" ` vs. `eval $cmd` makes a difference and the same for just `$cmd` without the `eval`.

Comment: Sure! Please go ahead and update the answer. 
Also, if you find this helpful, please accept the answer ;)